# Highlight text without call commands in pdf-tools

Tags: pdf-tools

Can I enter some 'highlight-mode' in `pdf-tools` that I can select and highlight text immediately without calling `pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation` or <kbd>C-c C-a h</kbd>?

Thanks!